# Supress IntelliSense errors in Arduino Visual Studio 2019 Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 with the VisualMicro Plugin to develop C++ AVR Code. In some cases I am using non-constant array lengths, for example like this:

```
char name[strlen(prefix) + strlen("MyDevice_01") + 1] = "";
```

which causes

> E2404 "function call must have a constant value in a constant
>   expression"

I have tried using

```
#pragma warning(disable: E2404)
```

aswell as

```
#pragma warning(disable: 2404)
```

to disable it, but that didn't make a change. How do I properly disable this as this makes it impossible to see "real" errors that I care about before compilation.

Comment: I'm afraid it's impossible.

Comment: How about avoiding using VLA?

Comment: @VTT Thats difficult on a Microcontroller due to the very limited RAM, if I just make the buffer bigger I will very soon hit that limit.

Comment: Use a constexpr ?

Comment: Is there something preventing you from using dynamic memory allocation? Note that failure to allocate VLA is not recoverable in general.